# match regex and replace bug with special charakters

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory, file-writing, powershell-module

I've built a script to read all Active Directory Group Memberships and save them to a file.
Problem is, the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet outputs all groups like this:

```
CN=Group_Name,OU=Example Mail,OU=Example Management, DC=domain,DC=de
```

So I need to do a bit of a regex and/or replacement magic here to replace the whole line with just the first string beginning from "CN=" to the first ",".

The result would be like this:

```
Group_Name
```

So, there is one AD group that's not gonna be replaced. I already got an idea why tho, but I don't know how to work around this. In our AD there is a group with a special character, something like this:

```
CN=AD_Group_Name+up,OU=Example Mail,OU=Example Management, DC=domain,DC=de
```

So, because of the little "+" sign, the whole line doesn't even get touched.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```cs
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Get Username
Write-Host "Please enter the Username you want to export the AD-Groups from."
$UserName = Read-Host "Username"

# Set Working-Dir and Output-File Block:
$WorkingDir = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop"
Write-Host "Working directory is set to " + $WorkingDir
$OutputFile = $WorkingDir + "\" + $UserName + ".txt"

# Save Results to File
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName |
    select -Property distinguishedName |
    Out-File $OutputFile -Encoding UTF8

# RegEx-Block to find every AD-Group in Raw Output File and delete all
# unnaccessary information:
[regex]$RegEx_mark_whole_Line = "^.*"
# The ^ matches the start of a line (in Ruby) and .* will match zero or more
# characters other than a newline
[regex]$RegEx_mark_ADGroup_Name = "(?<=CN=).*?(?=,)"
# This regex matches everything behind the first "CN=" in line and stops at
# the first "," in the line. Then it should jump to the next line.

# Replace-Block (line by line): Replace whole line with just the AD group
# name (distinguishedName) of this line.
foreach ($line in Get-Content $OutputFile) {
    if ($line -like "CN=*") {
        $separator = "CN=",","
        $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
        $ADGroup = $line.Split($separator, $option)
        (Get-Content $OutputFile) -replace $line, $ADGroup[0] |
            Set-Content $OutputFile -Encoding UTF8
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do regex acrobatics. You could simply use `Get-ADGroup -Identity <DistinguishedName> | Select-Object -Property Name` to get only the name of the group

Comment: That one helped a lot, thank you :D Should have read the man page more carefully xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, depending on what you're doing here this might or might not be a good idea. The CN is /not/ immutable so if you're storing it somewhere as a key you're likely to run into problems down the road. The `objectGUID` property of the group is a good primary key, though.

As far as getting this value, I think you can simplify this a lot. The `name` property that the cmdlet outputs will always have your desired value:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership <username> | select name
```

Answer (score 1):

Your group name contains a character (`+`) that has a special meaning in a regular expression (one or more times the preceding expression). To disable special characters escape the search string in your replace operation:

```
... -replace [regex]::Escape($line), $ADGroup[0]
```

However, I fail to see what you need that replacement for in the first place. Basically you're replacing a line in the output file with a substring from that line *that you already extracted before*. Just write that substring to the output file and you're done.

```
$separator = 'CN=', ','
$option    = [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
(Get-Content $OutputFile) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split($separator, $option)[0]
} | Set-Content $OutputFile
```

Better yet, use the `Get-ADObject` cmdlet to expand the names of the group members:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName |
    Get-ADObject |
    Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, all three tips are really helpful man. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar's answer is much better in terms of using the regex, but I believe that in this case you could do a dirty workaround with the IndexOf function. In your if-statement you could do the following:

```
if ($line -like "CN=*") {
    $ADGroup = $line.Substring(3, $line.IndexOf(',')-3)
    }
```

The reason this works here is that you know the output will begin with CN=YourGroupName meaning that you know that the string you want begins at the 4th character. Secondly, you know that the group name will not contain any comma, meaning that the IndexOf(',') will always find the end of that string so you don't need to worry about the [nth occurrence of a string in a string](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/1plvw0/replace_nth_occurrence_of_a_word_in_a_string/).

Comment: That is really helpful for future regex stuff, thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries! The .indexOf also takes strings, so if you for example are unsure of where the CN= is in the string you could also do a .IndexOf('CN='). There is also the .LastIndexOf which gives you the last entry of a charcter, very useful for finding the ends of paths when doing .LastIndexOf('\').